# A fast way to fill contours with the ability to export to a polygon-like format

Tags: javascript, algorithm, html5-canvas, polygon, flood-fill

I have a number of medical pictures presented on canvas, as an example below.

[image: knee]

I’m trying to make a tool that allows you to select any area of ​​the image with the tool in the form of an expandable circle, and fill in only that part of it that doesn't go beyond the outline in which the original click pixel was located. A filled outline is drawn on a separate canvas layer.

Now I use the most common **iterative stack implementation** of flood fill with variable tolerance (comparison function). [*You can familiarize yourself with it here*](https://github.com/tuzz/n-dimensional-flood-fill/blob/master/lib/floodFill.js). Everything doesn't work very well, especially in pictures where there are no strong contrast differences and in high-resolution images, everything else is pretty slow.

[image: flood fill result]

I had the idea to create a **state container** and look for whether the desired filled outline exists there and if so, then just replace the canvas pixel array (though, again, I will have to resort to some additional processing, the canvas pixel array contains 4 channel, while at the output of the algorithm only 1 is obtained and just replacing the content doesn't work, you need to replace each pixel with a pixel divided into 4 channels) instead of a slow flood fill each time. But this approach has one significant problem: **memory consumption**. As you might guess, a filled outline, especially of a decent resolution alone, can take up quite a lot of space, and their set becomes a real problem of memory consumption.

It was decided to store the finished contours in the form of polygons and extracting them from the container simply fill them with faster [context fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fill). The algorithm used allows me to output a set of boundaries, but due to the features of the algorithm, this array is unordered and connecting the vertices in this order, we get only a partially filled outline (right picture). Is there a way to sort them in such a way that I could only connect them and get a closed path (the holes that are in the filled outline in the left picture shouldn't be a priori, so we don’t have to worry about them)?

[image: flood fill][image: resulted path based on boundaries]

Summing up, due to the not-so-best fill job, I think to use a different algorithm / implementation, but I don’t know which one. **Here are some of my ideas:**

1. Use a different implementation, for example, a line scanning method. As far as I know, [*here is one of the fastest and most effective implementations of the algorithm among open sources*](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6017/QuickFill-An-efficient-flood-fill-algorithm).
   Pros: possible efficiency and speed.
   Cons: I need to somehow convert the result to a polygon, rewrite the algorithm to javascript (probably [emscripten](https://emscripten.org), can do it well, but in any case I will have to rewrite a considerable part of the code).
2. Use a completely different approach.

   a) I don’t know, but maybe the Canny detector can be useful for extracting the polygon. But as far as the use of the program is meant on the client side, it will be unprofitable to extract all the boundaries, it is necessary to figure out how to process only the necessary section, and not the entire picture.

   b) Then, knowing the border, use any sufficiently fast fill algorithm that simply won't go beyond the boundaries found.

I'll be glad to know about some other ways, and even better to see ready-made implementations in javascript

**UPD:**

For a better understanding, the tool cursor and the expected result of the algorithm are presented below.

[image: tool cursor][image: expected result]

Comment: I don't know how you compute the contours, but you may use opencv to do it. (there is a js version). Then you can approximate the contour with approxPolyDp. But I I have not really understood whether you could hint the 'center' of the contour you want, nor if the "white" hole was meant to be kept (like you need two polygons, one for the outershape and one for the hole) or not (just need of the polygon of the outer shape (looking like a circle))

Comment: @grodzi Thanks for the idea! I can get the click coordinate (the place where it was decided to use the tool), but I can only get the size of the captured image after the user releases the mouse. The idea is that after receiving the filled countour, process it using OpenCV and extract the polygon? About the first picture, I clarified that holes in the made contour are result of errors in the operation of the algorithm (maybe the tone is different there, but more likely, the algorithm leaves gaps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with opencv

Below should work or eventually use the **fiddle link** provided inside the code snippet

Of interest: approxPolyDP which may be sufficient for your needs (check [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm))

```js
// USE FIDDLE
// https://jsfiddle.net/c7xrq1uy/

async function loadSomeImage() {
  const ctx = document.querySelector('#imageSrc').getContext('2d')
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
  const img = new Image()
  img.crossOrigin = ''
  img.src = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiZ7z.png'

  img.onload = () => {
    const imgwidth = img.offsetWidth
    const imgheight = img.offsetHeight
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, 400, 400) 
  }
}

function plotPoints(canvas, points, color = 'green', hold = false){
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  !hold && ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400)
  ctx.strokeStyle = color

  Object.values(points).forEach(ps => {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(ps[0].x, ps[0].y)
    ps.slice(1).forEach(({ x, y }) => ctx.lineTo(x,y))
    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.stroke()
  })
}
const binarize = (src, threshold) => {
  cv.cvtColor(src, src, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 0)
  const dst = new cv.Mat()
  src.convertTo(dst, cv.CV_8U)
  cv.threshold(src, dst, threshold, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
  cv.imshow('binary', dst)
  return dst
}
const flip = src => {
  const dst = new cv.Mat()
  cv.threshold(src, dst, 128, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
  cv.imshow('flip', dst)
  return dst
}
const dilate = (src) => {
  const dst = new cv.Mat()
  let M = cv.Mat.ones(3, 3, cv.CV_8U)
  let anchor = new cv.Point(-1, -1)
  cv.dilate(src, dst, M, anchor, 1, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, cv.morphologyDefaultBorderValue())
  M.delete()
  cv.imshow('dilate', dst)
  return dst
}
const PARAMS = {
  threshold: 102,
  anchor: { x: 180, y: 180 },
  eps: 1e-2
}
const dumpParams = ({ threshold, anchor, eps }) => {
  document.querySelector('#params').innerHTML = `thres=${threshold} (x,y)=(${anchor.x}, ${anchor.y}) eps:${eps}`
}
document.querySelector('input[type=range]').onmouseup = e => {
  PARAMS.threshold = Math.round(parseInt(e.target.value, 10) / 100 * 255)
  dumpParams(PARAMS)
  runCv(PARAMS)
}
document.querySelector('input[type=value]').onchange = e => {
  PARAMS.eps = parseFloat(e.target.value)
  dumpParams(PARAMS)
  runCv(PARAMS)
}
document.querySelector('#imageSrc').onclick = e => {
  const rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect()
  PARAMS.anchor = {
    x: e.clientX - rect.left,
    y: e.clientY - rect.top
  }
  dumpParams(PARAMS)
  runCv(PARAMS)
}
const contourToPoints = cnt => {
  const arr = []
  for (let j = 0; j < cnt.data32S.length; j += 2){
    let p = {}
    p.x = cnt.data32S[j]
    p.y = cnt.data32S[j+1]
    arr.push(p)
  }
  return arr
}
loadSomeImage()
dumpParams(PARAMS)
let CVREADY
const cvReady = new Promise((resolve, reject) => CVREADY = resolve)

const runCv = async ({ threshold, anchor, eps }) => {
  await cvReady
  const canvasFinal = document.querySelector('#final')
  const mat = cv.imread(document.querySelector('#imageSrc'))
  const binaryImg = binarize(mat, threshold, 'binary')
  const blurredImg = dilate(binaryImg)
  const flipImg = flip(blurredImg)
  var contours = new cv.MatVector()
  const hierarchy = new cv.Mat
  cv.findContours(flipImg, contours, hierarchy, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

  const points = {}
  let matchingPoints = null
  let matchingContour = null
  for (let i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i) {
  let minArea = 1e40
    const ci = contours.get(i)
    points[i] = contourToPoints(ci)
    if (anchor) {
      const point = new cv.Point(anchor.x, anchor.y)
      const inside = cv.pointPolygonTest(ci, point, false) >= 1
      const area = cv.contourArea(ci)
      if (inside && area < minArea) {
        matchingPoints = points[i]
        matchingContour = ci
        minArea = area
      }
    }
  }
  plotPoints(canvasFinal, points)

  if (anchor) {
    if (matchingPoints) {
      plotPoints(canvasFinal, [matchingPoints], 'red', true)
      if (eps) {
        const epsilon = eps * cv.arcLength(matchingContour, true)
        const approx = new cv.Mat()
        cv.approxPolyDP(matchingContour, approx, epsilon, true)
        const arr = contourToPoints(approx)
        console.log('polygon', arr)
        plotPoints(canvasFinal, [arr], 'blue', true)
      }
    }
  }
  mat.delete()
  contours.delete()
  hierarchy.delete()
  binaryImg.delete()
  blurredImg.delete()
  flipImg.delete()
}
function onOpenCvReady() {
  cv['onRuntimeInitialized'] = () => {console.log('cvready'); CVREADY(); runCv(PARAMS)}
}
// just so we can load async script
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = onOpenCvReady
script.src = 'https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js';
document.head.appendChild(script)
```

```css
canvas{border: 1px solid black;}
  .debug{width: 200px; height: 200px;}
```

```html
binarization threeshold<input type="range" min="0" max="100"/><br/>
eps(approxPolyDp) <input type="value" placeholder="0.01"/><br/>
params: <span id="params"></span><br/>
<br/>
<canvas id="imageSrc" height="400" width="400"/></canvas>
<canvas id="final" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
<br/>
<canvas class="debug" id="binary" height="400" width="400" title="binary"></canvas>
<canvas class="debug" id="dilate" height="400" width="400" title="dilate"></canvas>
<canvas class="debug" id="flip" height="400" width="400" title="flip"></canvas>
```

ps: polygon is output in the console

---

#### implem with mask

edit: in below snippet I had more fun and implemented the mask. We may make the snippet [full page] then hover over the first canvas.

```js
// USE FIDDLE
// https://jsfiddle.net/c7xrq1uy/

async function loadSomeImage() {
  const ctx = document.querySelector('#imageSrc').getContext('2d')
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
  const img = new Image()
  img.crossOrigin = ''
  img.src = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiZ7z.png'

  img.onload = () => {
    const imgwidth = img.offsetWidth
    const imgheight = img.offsetHeight
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, 400, 400) 
  }
}

function plotPoints(canvas, points, color = 'green', hold = false){
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  !hold && ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400)
  ctx.strokeStyle = color

  Object.values(points).forEach(ps => {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(ps[0].x, ps[0].y)
    ps.slice(1).forEach(({ x, y }) => ctx.lineTo(x,y))
    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.stroke()
  })
}
const binarize = (src, threshold) => {
  cv.cvtColor(src, src, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 0)
  const dst = new cv.Mat()
  src.convertTo(dst, cv.CV_8U)
  cv.threshold(src, dst, threshold, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
  cv.imshow('binary', dst)
  return dst
}
const flip = src => {
  const dst = new cv.Mat()
  cv.threshold(src, dst, 128, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
  cv.imshow('flip', dst)
  return dst
}
const dilate = (src) => {
  const dst = new cv.Mat()
  let M = cv.Mat.ones(3, 3, cv.CV_8U)
  let anchor = new cv.Point(-1, -1)
  cv.dilate(src, dst, M, anchor, 1, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, cv.morphologyDefaultBorderValue())
  M.delete()
  cv.imshow('dilate', dst)
  return dst
}
const PARAMS = {
  threshold: 102,
  anchor: { x: 180, y: 180 },
  eps: 1e-2,
  radius: 50
}
const dumpParams = ({ threshold, anchor, eps }) => {
  document.querySelector('#params').innerHTML = `thres=${threshold} (x,y)=(${anchor.x}, ${anchor.y}) eps:${eps}`
}
document.querySelector('input[type=range]').onmouseup = e => {
  PARAMS.threshold = Math.round(parseInt(e.target.value, 10) / 100 * 255)
  dumpParams(PARAMS)
  runCv(PARAMS)
}
document.querySelector('input[type=value]').onchange = e => {
  PARAMS.eps = parseFloat(e.target.value)
  dumpParams(PARAMS)
  runCv(PARAMS)
}
document.querySelector('#imageSrc').onclick = e => {
  const rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect()
  PARAMS.anchor = {
    x: e.clientX - rect.left,
    y: e.clientY - rect.top
  }
  dumpParams(PARAMS)
  runCv(PARAMS)
}
// sorry for the globals, keep code simple
let DST = null
let MATCHING_CONTOUR = null
let DEBOUNCE = 0
document.querySelector('#imageSrc').onmousemove = e => {
  if (Date.now() - DEBOUNCE < 100) return
  if (!MATCHING_CONTOUR || !DST) { return }
  const rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect()
  DEBOUNCE = Date.now()
  const x = e.clientX - rect.left
  const y = e.clientY - rect.top
  const dst = DST.clone()
  plotIntersectingMask(dst, MATCHING_CONTOUR, { anchor: { x, y }, radius: PARAMS.radius })
  dst.delete()
}
const contourToPoints = cnt => {
  const arr = []
  for (let j = 0; j < cnt.data32S.length; j += 2){
    let p = {}
    p.x = cnt.data32S[j]
    p.y = cnt.data32S[j+1]
    arr.push(p)
  }
  return arr
}
const plotIntersectingMask = (dst, cnt, { anchor, radius }) => {
  const { width, height } = dst.size()
  
  const contourMask = new cv.Mat.zeros(height, width, dst.type())
  const matVec = new cv.MatVector()
  matVec.push_back(cnt)
  cv.fillPoly(contourMask, matVec, [255, 255, 255, 255])

  const userCircle = new cv.Mat.zeros(height, width, dst.type())
  cv.circle(userCircle, new cv.Point(anchor.x, anchor.y), radius, [255, 128, 68, 255], -2)

  const commonMask = new cv.Mat.zeros(height, width, dst.type())
  cv.bitwise_and(contourMask, userCircle, commonMask)
  
  userCircle.copyTo(dst, commonMask)
  cv.imshow('final', dst)

  commonMask.delete()
  matVec.delete()
  contourMask.delete()
  userCircle.delete()
}
loadSomeImage()
dumpParams(PARAMS)
let CVREADY
const cvReady = new Promise((resolve, reject) => CVREADY = resolve)

const runCv = async ({ threshold, anchor, eps, radius }) => {
  await cvReady
  const canvasFinal = document.querySelector('#final')
  const mat = cv.imread(document.querySelector('#imageSrc'))
  const binaryImg = binarize(mat, threshold, 'binary')
  const blurredImg = dilate(binaryImg)
  const flipImg = flip(blurredImg)
  var contours = new cv.MatVector()
  const hierarchy = new cv.Mat
  cv.findContours(flipImg, contours, hierarchy, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

  const points = {}
  let matchingPoints = null
  let matchingContour = null
  for (let i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i) {
  let minArea = 1e40
    const ci = contours.get(i)
    points[i] = contourToPoints(ci)
    if (anchor) {
      const point = new cv.Point(anchor.x, anchor.y)
      const inside = cv.pointPolygonTest(ci, point, false) >= 1
      const area = cv.contourArea(ci)
      if (inside && area < minArea) {
        matchingPoints = points[i]
        matchingContour = ci
        minArea = area
      }
    }
  }
  plotPoints(canvasFinal, points)

  if (anchor) {
    if (matchingPoints) {
      MATCHING_CONTOUR = matchingContour
      plotPoints(canvasFinal, [matchingPoints], 'red', true)
      if (eps) {
        const epsilon = eps * cv.arcLength(matchingContour, true)
        const approx = new cv.Mat()
        cv.approxPolyDP(matchingContour, approx, epsilon, true)
        const arr = contourToPoints(approx)
        //console.log('polygon', arr)
        plotPoints(canvasFinal, [arr], 'blue', true)

        if (DST) DST.delete()
        DST = cv.imread(document.querySelector('#final'))
      }
    }
  }
  mat.delete()
  contours.delete()
  hierarchy.delete()
  binaryImg.delete()
  blurredImg.delete()
  flipImg.delete()
}
function onOpenCvReady() {
  cv['onRuntimeInitialized'] = () => {console.log('cvready'); CVREADY(); runCv(PARAMS)}
}
// just so we can load async script
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = onOpenCvReady
script.src = 'https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js';
document.head.appendChild(script)
```

```css
  canvas{border: 1px solid black;}
  .debug{width: 200px; height: 200px;}
  #imageSrc{cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
binarization threeshold<input type="range" min="0" max="100"/><br/>
eps(approxPolyDp) <input type="value" placeholder="0.01"/><br/>
params: <span id="params"></span><br/>
<br/>
<canvas id="imageSrc" height="400" width="400"/></canvas>
<canvas id="final" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
<br/>
<canvas class="debug" id="binary" height="400" width="400" title="binary"></canvas>
<canvas class="debug" id="dilate" height="400" width="400" title="dilate"></canvas>
<canvas class="debug" id="flip" height="400" width="400" title="flip"></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow! This is really impressive, I was especially pleased with the performance.

I also mentioned my tool and the fact that it implements flood fill. The idea is that the fill is limited by the boundaries of the contours (those that result from findContours) on the one hand, if we reach the borders and the size of the tool cursor on the other hand (the cursor is in a circle). OpenCV has a built-in fill function (https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=floodfill#floodfill). What do you think is best to implement this tool?

Comment: 1) Use the flood fill function and try to play with the upDiff parameter, which would not allow us to go beyond the border, forgetting about the search for contours, and then extract it as a polygon (does this allow openCV without searching for contours?)

Comment: 2) Extract the contours and simply paint over the circle until it reaches the borders using *Set* ( https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvset#set), and when we reach the border, then merge (like LEFT or RIGHT JOIN[https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15] in SQL) the contours, cutting off the part of the circle that goes outside (for sure, OpenCV has a suitable merge function, I just don’t know about it, because I did not have to work with it)

Comment: I am not sure to understand the goal and the constraints you have. It is to paint the area delimited in blue ? @NikitaKobtsev

Comment: edit: as far as I understand you ask whether floodfill is better than findContours algorithm to ...find the contours. I would just use findContours because it feels it is made specifically for that. But use what is adapted to your situation @NikitaKobtsev

Comment: no, you misunderstood a little. My task is to fill the selected area, which should not go beyond the boundaries of the contour. That is, the user can select some radius of the fill, with the center of the fill at any point in the contour. My task is to prevent the spread of the fill beyond the contour, while the final result should be a polygon. Now I doubt whether I should use a fill fill or it can somehow be solved differently. **For a better understanding, I updated the post.**

Comment: I also have a question about your use of OpenCV. Did I understand correctly that what you used as an **dilate** function is nothing more than an extension of the white contours? So you artificially suppressed some noise, instead of using something like Gaussian (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function)? Or I'm wrong?

Comment: The purpose of me using dilatation is indeed to expand white or more precisely to **connect** very near pixels so they make a contour. The goal is **not** to make the image smoother.
As for the filling, with numpy that woul'd be just intersecting the masks (the user disk and the contour area).

Comment: In OpenVC intersecting analog seems to be this - https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d4d/tutorial_js_image_arithmetics.html. Thank you so much for all the tips and for working code snippet, I'm very grateful to you for this!

Comment: Indeed nice find @NikitaKobtsev I wanted to have a try already, I have edited post with the example of applying a mask. I do not care whether user mouse lies within a region but since we know how to detect whether we are inside the contour, this should be straightfoward

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213509/discussion-between-nikita-kobtsev-and-grodzi).